# Sort TreeView Automatically Upon Adding Nodes

Tags: .net, winforms, sorting, treeview

Is there an easy way to add nodes to a WinForms .NET TreeView control where the new nodes being added are inserted at the correct index so the entire list of nodes is sorted alphabetically? Pretty much having the same result as `TreeView.Sort()`.

I have a TreeView that continually grows to a couple hundred nodes. The user can view this TreeView in real time as it grows. I'd prefer to just insert the nodes at the correct index, rather than calling TreeView.Sort() each time after a node is added.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In winforms, you can simply set the TreeView's `.Sorted` property to `True`.

> When Sorted is set to true, the
>   TreeNode objects are sorted in
>   alphabetical order by their Text
>   property values. You should always use
>   BeginUpdate and EndUpdate to maintain
>   performance when adding a large
>   quantity of items to a sorted
>   TreeView. When the text of an existing
>   node is changed, you must call Sort to
>   resort the items.

Ref [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.sorted.aspx)

Comment: Interestingly enough (to me at least) is that the .Sorted property doesn't show up in the VS property list for the TreeView nor in the Intellisense.  Perhaps it's an oversight.  The MSDN docs, as you pointed out, clearly mention it but a lot of times I tend to "hit the dot key" to access the properties initially and then check the docs out if I don't see what I'm looking for.  I initially overlooked that Sorted property and it definitely made a difference in the efficiency of sorting the list.  It was much faster to set .Sorted to true initially than call Sort() afterwards.

Comment: For me it also does not show up in the properties list, but coding manually also works -- tree.Sorted = true

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter.aspx if you want to set the sorter

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you create new classes that inherits from `TreeView` and `TreeNodeCollection`? The new `TreeView` will use your new `TreeNodeCollection` and you can override the `Add()` method of the `TreeNodeCollection` to do what you're suggesting.

The method would have to:
1. Find the correct position to insert into and 2. Insert the new node.

The most trivial implementation would iterate through the collection until `thisNode.value<=newNode.value<nextNode.value`. Then insert before `nextNode.Index`. You could see a performance increase if you use a different search algorithm, depending on the size of the collection. (Something like a binary search comes to mind.)

Note: You could also just create an extension method on a `TreeNodeCollection` that does the same thing. However, overriding the `Add()` method ensures your `TreeView` is *always* sorted. Creating only an extension method may lead to undefined results if it is not already sorted before your `AddIntoSorted()` call.

Comment: This could've easily changed since your post is 6 years old, but it looks like you cannot subclass `TreeNodeCollection` now. It has a [constructor with the `internal` access modifier.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNodeCollection.cs)

Comment: @DarrenHale Interesting. And annoying, since I guess you'll have to reinvent the wheel then make your new `TreeView` use the new collection. Thanks for the heads-up.