# How to reset Treeview to default display after Treeview.Sort?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, treeview

I was trying to display a treeview's nodes alphabetically and managed to get it done simply by:

```
treeview1.Sort();
```

it does the job of sorting. but then I'd like to have the option to put the treeview back to its original display state (without the alphabetic sorting).

[on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390802/sort-treeview-automatically-upon-adding-nodes) I saw that I might be able to use the treeview's property: `.sorted` and set it to true or false but it didn't do anything for me.

I have the data in the control, it's already set in design time.

what is the best way to do this?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking for the phantom Unsort() method.  The one that uses the 200+ megabyte copy of what the tree looked like before you sorted it.  Of course it isn't there, separate the data from the view and it becomes simple.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the answer, so you mean, the best way to do this might be to serialize the data to an XML document and then deserialize it back to the treeview after clearing all its sorted nodes?

Comment: No. He meant what he said. Until you explain just where the data come from and how they get into the tree we can't help you with more concrete advice..

Comment: @TaW I thought it was obvious and that Hans also got me, the data is in the control, it's already set in design time. So he offered to seperare it and I wanted to be sure this is how

Comment: Not as obvious as you thought. But since that's how it is you may simply put it in a LoadTree() routine instead of the designer which you can whenever you want to.. Not as flexible as an XML file but self-contained.

Comment: If the tree contains more than a few nodes you may want to save the work you put in the designer. With some care and caution and a little luck you should be able copy the right portions from the formDesigner.cs file and stuff it into a LoadInitial() method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course getting the content from an outside source would be the most flexible way to fill the `Tree`, but..

..as the content of the tree has been added in the designer then if there is a lot of data involved the best route may be to salvage these data by moving the designer code into a magical `Unsort`-function you can call anytime.

Have a good look at the form's `Designer.cs` file! Here you can find two sections that deal with the loading of the `TreeView`:

- The first sit inside the 'forbidden' part: `InitializeComponent()`with the dire warning that you shouldn't change anything in there. Well, don't worry all we do is copy a few lines from it to the unsort function..

What we need are all lines that declare and create the nodes. They look like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("John");
```

Now scroll down to the section the starts with

```
   // 
   // treeView1
   //
```

We don't care about the first few lines that assign a `Name` and a `Location` to the `TreeView`. But we want **all** the following lines that set the `Names` and the `Texts` of **all** the `Nodes`; and also all lines the add the root nodes to the `TreeView`..

We copy all this into a function that starts by clearing the `Nodes` and resetting the `Sorted` property. Then come all the lines we have salvaged from the Designer.

The result could look like this:

```
void unsortTree()
{
   this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
   this.treeView1.Sorted = false;
    
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("John");
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Paul");
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("George");
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Ringo");
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode5 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Beatles",
                 new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[] 
                 {treeNode1,  treeNode2, treeNode3, treeNode4});
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode6 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Byrds");
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode7 = 
         new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Bee Gees");

   // 
   // treeView1
   // 

   treeNode1.Name = "Knoten2";        treeNode1.Text = "John";
   treeNode2.Name = "Knoten3";        treeNode2.Text = "Paul";
   treeNode3.Name = "Knoten4";        treeNode3.Text = "George";
   treeNode4.Name = "Knoten6";        treeNode4.Text = "Ringo";
   treeNode5.Name = "Knoten0";        treeNode5.Text = "Beatles";
   treeNode6.Name = "Knoten1";        treeNode6.Text = "Byrds";
   treeNode7.Name = "Knoten7";        treeNode7.Text = "Bee Gees";

   this.treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[]
                                { treeNode5,   treeNode6, treeNode7});

}
```

We you have tested that this works fine you can delete the nodes from the tree in the designer and add a call to the function to the form load. Do not keep the data in two places!!

Note: As this recreates the Tree content from scratch all **user input** is lost. If the user can check `CheckBoxes` or edit `Labels` you should consider writing a treesave and a treeload function! (Not necessarily targeting a file, maybe just an invisible helper-treeview..)

Note 2:

Since the `TreeView` indeed does contain `CheckBoxes` (but neither adds nor deletes `Nodes` nor changes `Texts`) we should store and restore the `CheckStates`.

Adding a `Dictionary` at class level and these two recursive helper functions is almost all we need:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> tvCheckStates = null;

void storeChecks(TreeNode node)
{
    if (tvCheckStates.Keys.Contains(node.Name))
        throw new Exception("duplicate node name:" + node.Name);
    else tvCheckStates.Add(node.Name, node.Checked);

    foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes) storeChecks(n);
}

void restoreChecks(TreeNode node)
{
    if (tvCheckStates.Keys.Contains(node.Name))
        node.Checked = tvCheckStates[node.Name];
    else throw new Exception("node not found:" + node.Name);

    foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes) restoreChecks(n);
}
```

Finally we call them at the very start and end of the 'unsort':

```
  {
      if (tvCheckStates == null && treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0) 
          tvCheckStates = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
      else if (treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0) tvCheckStates.Clear();
      foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes) storeChecks(node);
      //..

      //..
      if (tvCheckStates != null && treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0) 
          foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes) restoreChecks(node);
  }
```

Note that the `Node Names` must be **unique** (as they should).

To persist the states across program runs it should be enough to save the names of the checked nodes..

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @TaW based on your comment earlier I've already done everything you just proposed but I got stuck with that the nodes always came back sorted even though I cleared the treenodes and re-added them as new Treenodes but then your code example saved me since I needed the line: `this.treeView1.Sorted = false;` now everything works! Thanks again!

Comment: assuming nodes will never change but their check state will, Do you think it will be a good idea to save the check state for each node as a bool in the application settings (user scoped)? Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorted is an intellisense-hidden property. But you had it in your post ;-) -  Hm, I need more info for an advice. So there is a CheckState? 1. Do you want it to persistent between program runs? 2. Will the number of nodes change? 3. Do you add anything else, e.g. Tags to the nodes? - (I'm actually sound asleep atm, so don't expect back me in the next couple of hours..)

Comment: Thanks @TaW yes about the .sorted, I had it in the original post but didn't know how to implement it since it didn't work as I thought it would originally.. so.. now I got it. about the checkstate, yes, there is a checkstate and the number of nodes doesn't change. and I do need it persistent between application runs.. so that's why I figured it could be a good way to do it.  Thanks again.

Comment: BTW I'm sure my question will help plenty of others since I couldn't find a clear answer to my question. sometimes down voting is just wrong imho, people who look for this info could turn away just because of the down votes.

Comment: Yes, if you want it to persist that is a good way to do it. Depending on your data it wlil help if either the node Texts or the node Names are unique. for a non-persistent storage I would use a Dictionary<string, bool>.. G'night..

Comment: Good night.. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure. I have added code to store and restore the CheckStates now. Persisting them across program run is left for you ;-)